# What is an efficient method for extracting data from a string into a Map?

Tags: c++, regex, string, dictionary

This is in C++. Let's say I have a string that looks like this `"[05]some words here [13]some more words here [17]and so on"`

I want to split this string into a `Map<int, std::string>` with the number as the key and the text up to the next code as the value. The brackets are to be completely ignored.

So far I've been getting by with the standard library and SDL (I'm making a small game), but I'm willing to install boost or any other library that would help.

My first thought was to either use some of Boosts Regex functions to do a kind of regex find and replace, or to simply convert it to a char array going through every character looking for the brackets and recording the number inside but that seems like it would be inefficient, especially since I'm sure there's probably a popular method to do this in C++.

Comment: *a char array going through every character ... it would be inefficient*. Why it is inefficient?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `substr()` and `find_first_of()` to extract the actual data from a string as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::map;


map<int,string> StrToMap(const string& str)
{
    map<int, string> temMap;

    for (int i(0); i < str.size(); ++i){
        if ( str[i] == '[' ){
            string tempIdx = str.substr(i+1, str.find_first_of("]",i)-i-1 );
            int a = i+str.find_first_of("]",i)-i+1;
            int b = str.find_first_of("[",a)-1;
            if ( b < 0 )
                b = str.size();
            string tempStr = str.substr(a, b-a);
            int idx = std::stoi(  tempIdx );
            temMap[idx] = tempStr; 
        }
    }

    return temMap;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   map<int, string> temMap = StrToMap("[05]some words here [13]some more words here [17]and so on");

  for (std::map<int, string>::const_iterator it=temMap.begin(); it!=temMap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
5 some words here
13 some more words here
17 and so on
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the error of my ways. Your method is the fastest according to my tests, and that's the opposite of what I was expecting!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [regex_token_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) for this.  Here's the basic idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

map<int, string> extract( const std::string & s )
{
    map<int, string> m; 
    static const regex r( "\\s*\\[(\\d+)\\]" );
    sregex_token_iterator tok( s.begin(), s.end(), r, { -1, 1 } );
    tok++;  // Skip past the first end-of-sequence iterator.

    for( sregex_token_iterator end; tok != end; )
    {
        int num = stoi( *tok, nullptr, 10 );
        if( ++tok != end )
        {
            m.emplace( make_pair( num, *tok++ ) );
        }
    }
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    auto m = extract("[05]some words here [13]some more words here [17]and so on");
    for( auto & p : m ) cout << p.first << ": '" << p.second << "'" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, this is searching for and extracting the pattern `\s*\[(\d+)\]\s*`, which means it will drop any whitespace before and after the square brackets, and create a matching group to match at least one digit.

By using `{-1, 1}` on the iterator, we're asking for the iteration sequence to provide all text prior to the match, followed by matching group 1.

Output:

```
5: 'some words here'
13: 'some more words here'
17: 'and so on'
```

Working example is [here](http://ideone.com/qwPIbU)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to learn about how to use regex_token_iterator thanks to your example!

Answer (score 0):

You can split string by '[' characters and collect parts to the vector. Then for each element of the vector split it on two parts (before ']' and after). Convert first to the number and put everything in map. It's all will be standard std methods.